# How to view my openldap directory tree structure

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

I have openldap on a linux machine. Is there a way to view the directory tree structure so I can see the DN's of users and how the directory is structured? I want to better understand the structure so it can help me form the right queries I am using in a script using the python-ldap module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Apache Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) for such activities. But there are [many others](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Browsers).